# KStreamBuilder vs KafkaUtils.createDirectStream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Would like to know the difference between KstreamBuilder.stream() vs KafkaUtils.createDirectStream() which is best one to use and why.

The one thing i know is KafkaUtils.createDirectStream() returns DStream

Comment: You are equating two different frameworks. KStreams are an abstraction provided by the Apache Kafka - Kafka Streams project, while DStreams is a Spark Streaming abstraction. Both have their pro's and con's.

Comment: Just a side note: there is no "project" called Kafka Streams. The Kafka project has a Streams API (aka Kafka Streams) and it is part of Apache Kafka. You can describe it as a module of Kafka if you wish though, but it's deeply integrated into Kafka core and there is just one Kafka project :)